# Is it possible to make JSF FacesServlet work with AspectJ?

Tags: maven, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, aspectj

I'm trying to write sample application showing the intergration between `JSF`'s FacesServlet running on tomcat and `AspectJ`. I've created two projects:

1) `JSF` project:

`pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- JSF 2.0 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pac</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.pac</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectj-lib</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`ManagedBean`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        test();
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        test();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int test(){
        System.out.println("Test is invoked");
        return 10;
    }

}
```

2) `aspectj-lib` which contains all aspects

`pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

`TestAspect.aj`:

```
public aspect TestAspect {
    pointcut t(): execution(public !static * *(..));

    int around() : t() {
        System.out.println("Test string");    
        int v = proceed();
        return v * 2;
    }
}
```

So, I expected the aspect should have come into play when `test()` was being called. But it didn't, all I saw in the console's output was:

```
Test is invoked
Test is invoked
Test is invoked
Test is invoked
```

`Test string` defined in the aspect was not being printed.

How can I integrate `JSF` and `AspectJ`? Is there a documentation?

Maybe I should add additional confiduration information in `web.xml/faces-config.xml` or create another config file to make it work?

Comment: I don't do AspectJ, but based on my experience with Spring, it might be necessary to use the Spring Framework to bridge AspectJ and JSF. AspectJ and Mojarra/JSF provide managed execution contexts, and as long as those contexts don't intersect somewhere, neither container can do anything for the other. If you're looking to implement AOP in JSF, you should consider using CDI-provided AOP instead of AspectJ

Comment: @kolossus No, it's not neccesary. He just had to use load-time weaving instead of compile-time one.

Comment: You should probably post the implementation as an answer here

Comment: @kolossus I did it. Maybe someone else will be able to make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation reference](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html)

The answer was quite simple. All we had to do was to ***replace*** compile-time weaving with load-time weaving. Load-time weaving means that we're going to weave our classes when JVM tries to load their. Replace is neccesary, beacause compile-time weaving and load-time weaving are not compatible with each other. So, assume we have two projects:

```
aspects-lib
    |---pom.xml
    |---src/main/aspect
             |---TestAspect.aj   -- aspect itself


JavaServerFaces
    |---pom.xml
    |---src/main/java
    |          |---TestBean.java    -- The bean which methods we want to intercept
    |---src/main/resources
    |          |---META-INF/aop.xml -- That file configures the load-time weaving
    |---src/main/webapp
               |
        webpages, omited
```

Let's consider the configuration now.

`aop.xml` (load-time weaving configuration):

```
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="fully.qualified.ascpect.name"/>
  </aspects>

  <weaver options="-verbose">
    <include within="package.you.want.to.weave.*"/>
  </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

`aspect-lib/pom.xml`:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- IMPORTANT!!!!!! -->
                    <!-- DISABLING COMPILE TIME WEAVING -->
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
               <XterminateAfterCompilation>true</XterminateAfterCompilation>
                    <!-- DISABLING COMPILE TIME WEAVING -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

`JavaServerFaces/pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
            <!-- aspect-lib dependency -->
    </dependency>

    <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.7</version>
         <configuration>
            <outxml>true</outxml>
            <XterminateAfterCompilation>true</XterminateAfterCompilation>
            <aspectLibraries>
                <aspectLibrary>
                    <!-- your aspect lib -->
                </aspectLibrary>
            </aspectLibraries>
         </configuration>

         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>
         </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**And one more thing**: You should add the following option to the JVM in order to allow your `servlet-container/app-server` perfrom load-time weaving:

```
-javaagent:pathto/aspectjweaver.jar
```

The corresponding jar-file should be added to server's resources.